# Showing SQL data in datagridview using Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I have setup a sql server to hold our darts leaderboard results. I am now trying to pull the data out of the sql database and show it in a `datagridview` within my `windows form`. I have managed to show the data in `Powershell ISE`, but not having much luck with the form side. Below is my code and what I have tried. Any help would be much appreciated

```
$connection                  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = "Server=MYSERVER, PORT; Uid=USERNAME; Pwd=PASSWORD; Database=DBTABLE"
$connection.Open()
$command             = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = "SELECT C_Name,C_Wins FROM T_Darts301"
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null
$dataSet.Tables
$dataGridView1.DataSource=[System.Collections.ArrayList]$dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doumentation for the [`DataGridView.DataSource` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource):

> The DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms
> data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that
> implements one of the following interfaces:
>
> [...]
>
> - The `IListSource` interface, such as the `DataTable` and `DataSet`
>   classes.

So assign the resulting `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property:

```
$dataGridView1.DataSource = $dataSet.Tables[0]
```